# Soundcloud API - retrieving users followers in a particular order

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, soundcloud

Recently I've got an idea to make a Chrome extension for own purposes which should use the SoundCloud API. But I've found out that functionality of the API is quite limited or maybe those features that I need are not documented/I just didn't find an answer.
For example, first of all I would like to retrieve some users followers in a particular order. To clarify, the response should be sorted by the followers_count -> descending. So the first follower in the response should be the follower with the maximum number of followers around ALL the followers of the user we have made that request for. And so on.
After a lot of searching @ google I have found an old thread where a guy asked about the similar feature and someone from the SC support told him to use "&order=value" in the request, which worked fine , but is deprecated and not working now.
I would like to know if that is possible at this moment and if not - can we expect for this feature to be added soon? I believe this is not a complicated thing at all.

So in short what I need is retrieving any users followers_count in a particular order. That is the first question. If we'll have success here we'll go deeper. Thanks ahead. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to retrieve user followers in desc order from Souncloud.

Lets suppose we have five users with Sound-Cloud profile URLs

1. https://soundcloud.com/drop-the-bassline
2. https://soundcloud.com/certifiedjackin
3. https://soundcloud.com/ravingkoko
4. https://soundcloud.com/twenty4sevenedm
5. https://soundcloud.com/pr-gangstahouse

Code

```
// Need Soundcloud SDK
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// Create Object 
$client = new Services_Soundcloud(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

$result = array();
$urls = array(array
                (
                    'link' => 'https://soundcloud.com/drop-the-bassline',
                ),
             array
                (
                    'link' => 'https://soundcloud.com/certifiedjackin',
                ),
            array
                (
                    'link' => 'https://soundcloud.com/ravingkoko',
                ),
            array
                (
                    'link' => 'https://soundcloud.com/twenty4sevenedm',
                ),
            array
                (
                    'link' => 'https://soundcloud.com/pr-gangstahouse',
                )
                );

foreach($urls as $key=>$u){
    try{
         $response = json_decode($client->get('resolve', array('url' => $u['link']), array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true)));
         $result[$key]['followers_count']= $response->followers_count;
    }catch(Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e){
         echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }

}

foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    // replace 0 with the field's index/key
    $dates[$key]  = $row['followers_count'];
}
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $result);
//echo"<pre>";print_r($result);echo"</pre>";
```

`$data` contain information as you need.